# MPR Test for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2014

**When I run MPR test for Microsoft azure, I got below two issues:**

**1. Which parameters I have to select in 'SQL Server 2014 Online Transaction Processing and Data Warehouse Gold Tests'**

1. Partitioning
2. In-Memory OLTP Tables
3. Clustered Columnstore Index
4. Resource Governor
5. Encrypted Backups

**2.'Default Trace should be turn on'  Status shown as 'off', How to handle this?**

Answer (score 0):

1.Those tests are designed to see ,if your application passes them,one way I see them is select all,if you are not using those features,you will not see any issues.If you are using those,they will be tested to see if they meet criteria..

2.
This turns default trace on

```
sp_configure 'default trace enabled' ,1
reconfigure
```

Default trace runs always ,I am not sure why it is stopped in your infra .if you want to stop it,you can use below command

```
sp_configure 'default trace enabled' ,0
reconfigure
```

Comment: this is regarding 1, which features Azure provide default ??  like 4.Resource Governor 5.Encrypted Backups

Comment: this is regarding 2, sp_configure not supported for Azure